# Timeout for idle connection

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

I am using asyncore and asynchat modules to build a SMTP server (I used code from smtpd lib to build the SMTP server) but I have a problem with connection timeouts. When I open telnet connection to the SMTP server and leave it so, the connection is established althought no data exchange happens. I want to set timeout e.g 30 seconds and to close the idle connection by server if nothing comes from the client (else there could be an easy DOS vulnerability). I googled for a solution, read source codes and documentation but didn't found anything usable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to `asyncore` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html), `asyncore.loop()` has a timeout parameter, which defaults to 30 seconds. So apparently default already should be 30 seconds, you can try and play with it to suit your own needs.

> The timeout argument sets the timeout parameter for the appropriate
>   select() or poll() call, measured in seconds; the default is 30
>   seconds.

---

Ok, the above actually refers to `poll()` or `select()` timeout and not the idle timeout. 
As per [this page](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/726702-adding-idle-timeout-capabilities-asyncore), you can hack asyncore to support timeouts like this:

Add the following block to your own copy of `asyncore.poll` just after the `for fd in e:` block...

```
#handle timeouts
rw = set(r) + set(w)
now = time.time()
for f in (i for i in rw if i in map):
    map[f].lastdata = now
    for j in (map[i] for i in map if i not in rw):
        if j.timeout+j.lastdata now:
            #timeout!
            j.handle_close()
```

You ARE going to need to initialize .timeout and .lastdata members for
every instance, but that shouldn't be so bad (for a socket that
doesn't time out, I would actually suggest a 1 hour or 1 day timeout).

Comment: I tried it but this is probably other kind of timeout. When I set the loop timeout to any value, the behaviour doesn't change. I open a terminal, start telnet localhost 10025, the connection is established and I can communicate with the server. When I let it so for 10 minutes and return to the running telnet, I can continue with the communication.

Comment: Oh, indeed. I just read the code, it's the `poll()`/`select()` timeout.. Reading the code, there's no way to implement what you want out-of-box. I added a hacky solution to my answer, but not sure whether you want to hack asyncore itself.